# how change the data of a pie chart?

Tags: d3.js

I'm new on the D3, and I need some help on my graph.

I shall want to pass from a data to an other one in the same CSV file, but I just can't do a transition on the `d3.pie()`, I just need to pass from d.A2008 to d.A2015, but each time it bug.

My code:

```
var width = 600;
var height = 400;
var radius = 200;

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("border","1px solid black")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(200,200)");

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()  //va pemrettre d'attribuer de la couleur sur une échelle de données de type string
                .range(["red","blue","orange","yellow","pink","purple","green","white","grey","brown"]);

var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value (function(d,i){return d.A2008;});

var arc = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);


d3.csv("CAplateforme.csv", function(data){  
  var svg = canvas.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  svg.append("path")
      .attr("d",arc)
      .attr("fill", function(d,i){ return colorScale(d.data.A2008);});
       //.transition()
      // .duration(1500)
       //.delay(2000)
       //.attr("d",arc)
       //.attr("fill", function(d,i){ return colorScale(d.data.A2015);});

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d){return ". " + d.data.Type +" ("+ d.data.A2008 + ")";})
    .attr("fill", function(d){return colorScale(d.data.A2008);})
    .attr("y", function(d,i){return 20*(i+1);})
    enter code here.attr("transform","translate(250,-150)");
    //.transition()
    //.duration(1500)
    //.delay(2000)
    //.text(function(d){return ". " + d.data.Type +" ("+ d.data.A2015 + ")";})
    //.attr("fill", function(d){return colorScale(d.data.A2015);});

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're initializing your elements the wrong way. Try instead :

```
var svg = canvas.selectAll(".arc").data(pie(data));

//Here you put the code for the elements entering the DOM
svg.enter()
   .append(stuff you want to append)
   .and so on and so forth;

//And then you put the code for the elements transitioning
svg.transition()
   .duration(1500)
   .attr(and so on and so forth);
```